# Are Kolmogorov partial differential equations degenerate elliptic?

Tags: inequality, partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations, elliptic-operators

Let $\mu : \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d $ and $\sigma: \mathbb{R}^{d} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}  $ be smooth and Lipschitz continuous. Furthermore, let $\varphi : \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous and at most polynomially growing.

The equation
\begin{gather}
0 = \frac{1}{2} \text{Trace}[\sigma(x) \sigma(x) (\text{Hessian}_x (u))(\theta)] + \langle \mu (x) , (\nabla_x u) (\theta) \rangle - \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} (\theta) \\ \\ := F(\theta, u(\theta) , \nabla u (\theta), \text{Hessian} \ (u) (\theta)), \\ \\
u(0,x) = \varphi(x),
\end{gather}
with
$$ F : \mathbb{R}^{d+1} \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^{d+1} \times \mathbb{R}^{d+1 \times d+1} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $$ and $$ \theta = (t,x_1,...,x_d) $$
is called Kolmogorov partial differential equation.

A function $$H :\mathbb{R}^{d+1} \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^{d+1} \times \mathbb{R}^{d+1 \times d+1} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$ is called degenerate elliptic if, for any two symmetric matrices $A,B$ for which $B-A$ is positive definite, we have $$ H(x,s,v, A) \geq H(x,u,v,B) $$ for all $x, v \in \mathbb{R}^{d+1}$ and $s \in \mathbb{R}$.

Is $F$ degenerate elliptic? How could I prove this?

Comment: Your $F$ does not appear to really depend on $u$, am I wrong? Also, the equation is linear, so you can explicitly calculate $H(A) {-} H(B)$. Note that the equation is not intrinsically degenerate: This depends on the degeneracy of the volatility $\sigma$.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer. You are correct, $F$ does not depend on $u$. Which conditions do I need for $\sigma$ to make the equation degenerate elliptic?